# Spring WebFlux - SessionLocaleResolver

Tags: spring-webflux

I was trying to implement language changing in WebFlux like the following:

- the site sets it's default language
- when the user logs in his language preference is loaded into the
  session
- the locale should also be changeable by request parameter

For that purpose I'd copy `AcceptHeaderLocaleContextResolver`'s `resolveLocaleContext()` but the problem is: `ServerWebExchange`'s `getRequest()` returns a `ServerHttpRequest` but `getSession()` returns a `Mono<WebSession>`. Do I have to make a `block()` here? Or is there any other way to achieve what I want?

Also, is there a `LanguageChangeInterceptor`-like thing or I have to implement that too?

Edit: the method `resolveLocaleContext()` I'd like to edit is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/server/i18n/AcceptHeaderLocaleContextResolver.java), instead of `exchange.getRequest().getHeaders()` I'd write something like `exchange.getSession()...` but it returns reactive type.

Comment: can you post the code. I can rewrite it and post it back.

Comment: @piotrszybicki I've edited my question.

Comment: I see. You shouldn't call to block. You should handle it in a reactive way. Your method should return Mono<SomeType>. That is why i asked you to post full code. Not this just bits. Because I think there is some misunderstanding how that logic should be handled.

Comment: @piotrszybicki if my method returns a reactive type I'm not implementing the Spring interface, that's my problem. (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/i18n/LocaleContextResolver.html)

Comment: OK. Can you post a full code? Even if it won't compile. I just don't want to set up everything from scratch in my IDE. But if you are correct this seems like medium size whole in the implementation.