# SessionLocaleResolver equivalent in Spring WebFlux - resolve locale through session data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

If we need to resolve the locale value from session data, how can we implement this in a reactive way in Spring WebFlux?

For non-reactive web application, [`SessionLocaleResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/SessionLocaleResolver.html) is available to resolve the locale from session data.

For Spring WebFlux, the way to intercept the locale resolver is using [`LocaleContextResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/i18n/LocaleContextResolver.html). The default implementation provided in Spring Boot WebFlux starter is [`AcceptHeaderLocaleContextResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/i18n/AcceptHeaderLocaleContextResolver.html). The problem with this interface is that it only provides sync method `resolveLocaleContext(ServerWebExchange)`. If I need to resolve the locale from request query parameters or the `Accept-Language` headers, it works perfectly, because `ServerWebExchange` provides direct methods to access the request object, which in turn provides methods to access parameters and headers directly.

```kotlin
override fun resolveLocaleContext(exchange: ServerWebExchange): LocaleContext {
    val langParams = exchange.request.queryParams["lang"]
    var targetLocale: Locale? = null
    if (langParams != null && langParams.isNotEmpty()) {
        for (lang in langParams) {
            val locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(lang)
            if (locale != null) {
                targetLocale = locale
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return SimpleLocaleContext(targetLocale ?: Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US"))
}
```

However, if I need to resolve the locale from session data, there is a problem. `ServerWebExchange#getSession()` returns `Mono<WebSession>`. I am not able to get session data in a sync method unless I call `Mono#block()`. However, this is not an ideal, reactive way.

Is there any way to resolve this? Or are there any plan in Spring to change this?

(There was a similar question previously which got buried: [Spring WebFlux - SessionLocaleResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53467478))

Comment: `I am not able to get session data in a sync method` what is a `sync method`?

Comment: @Toerktumlare I meant getting a plain WebSession object rather than `Mono<WebSession>` in the current non-reactive `resolveLocaleContext(ServerWebExchange)` method without blocking, or if we have an intercept-able reactive method that does same thing.